# incremental backup of files using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have 10 files on remote server,I want to continuously check if there is any new file in the remote directory and if there is any new file it should be transferred to the local directory. I could write shell script to get the file but how do I get only the new files  to be transferred,new files can be 1 to 10 in number
Here is what i tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="abc"
ssh_host="host"
from_loc="/tmp/"
to_loc="/tmp/"
file="file.txt"

if ssh $ssh_host test -e $from_loc$file;
    then
        cd $to_loc
        sftp $user@$ssh_host <<EOF
cd $from_loc
get $file
bye
EOF
    else echo $file does not exist
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `rsync`. It does what you want and more.

See this [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/).

Comment: actually i require only the differential files between remote and local directory to be copied to a separate directory in local server.

Comment: can rsync be used with .ppk file?